# Two samples, proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion

I have two groups of samples, each group of size 8. Each sample comes from an individual $i = 1 \dots 16$ and is a proportion $m_i$ of DNA methylated sites at a specific position in a genome. This can take a value between 0 and 1. We can safely assume that there is no variability between samples if they were taken from the same individual (i.e., the proportion in a single individual is calculated from a very large population of DNA strands). The individuals from both groups are matched.

Now, more than one position has been tested (as above). Actually, almost half a million positions were tested, each of them corresponding to a proportion as described above. Effectively I have a matrix of the size $16 \times 5\cdot 10^5$, and each number in this matrix is a value between 0 and 1 corresponding to the proportion of DNA strands that are methylated in a specific sample at a specific genomic position.

Given that I have a very large number of positions in a genome tested, I have an idea what the distribution of these measurements can be. Most of the sites are either methylated or not methylated -- the value $m_i$ is close to 1 or close to 0:

[image: Histogram of $m_i$ values]

H0 is that the groups do not differ. I have applied a Wilcoxon signed rank test and a t test (although clearly the assumptions of the t test do not hold, but it is generally considered robust), the results were similar. However, I wonder whether there might be better approach that takes the specific distribution of the $m_i$ values.

Comment: It would be easier to answer the question with some more information.  There are sixteen individuals but way more than sixteen boxes on the histogram.  Are there lots of sites per individual?  Lots of measurements of methylation for each individual-site?

Comment: Precisely; there is a huge number of genome positions tested (half a million give or take a thousand). I will try to clarify my question.

Comment: Sorry to be a while getting back to this. Let me try to translate entirely into a statistical question and see if you agree. There is a variable $m_{ij}$, methylation of site $j$ for individual $i$. The variable is distributed with distribution function $F_{ij}$. The individuals are eight matched pairs. Let's sort them so that $i=1$ matches with $i=9$, $i=2$, matches with $i=10$, and so on. Then, the null hypothesis is $H_0:F_{ij}=F_{i+8,j} \; \textrm{for} \; i=1,…,8$. OK?

Comment: It's easy to make 16 individual mean methylations, $m_i=\frac{1}{J} \sum_{j=1}^Jm_{ij}$ ($J$ is the number of sites) and treat these like independent draws. I assume this is how you did Wilcoxon and t-tests. To do better than this, I think you need to know something about the correlation in the methylations between sites within individuals. For example, is there any notion of distance or type (not necessarily physical distance) between sites that lets you say "the methylation between these two sites is definitely uncorrelated because they are far apart/different types?"